# Why I need a 12 columns width form to fulfill a col-xs-8 column?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make clear the "total of 12 columns" clear in my head

I have a simple 2-8-2 row with a form in the middle div.

I'm using a classical form-horizontal form.

For a col-xs-8 div, in my opinion the total width of child row must be 8, col-xs-2 and col-xs-6.

But it doesn't fulfill my parent div.

By against a col-xs-2 + col-xs-10 fulfills my col-xs-8 parent div.

So it's right for a 12 width into a 8, but wrong for 8 into a 8 width parent ?
I don't understand, maybe my comprehension of bootstrap's grid system is wrong

I have a plunker to show the two forms.

http://plnkr.co/edit/toWeoV3cQna02IyzQLnF?p=preview

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="content" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>MENU</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      LEFT COL
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      MIDLE
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <legend>form with 12 colums in 8</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Label1</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-xs-10" value="expends to 100%">
        </div>
      </form>
      <hr>
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <legend>form with 8 colums in 8</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Label1</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-xs-6" value="Doesn't expend 100%">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      RIGHT COL
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I have missed ?

**The right explanation** from ckuijjer

With the initial .col-xs-8 it defined a column that is 8 out of 12 columns wide. With the .form-group it nest a new grid inside this column. This nested grid also consists of 12 columns *that are smaller than columns in the parent grid*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you nest Bootstrap's grid either by adding another `.row` or `.form-group` the nested columns should again add up to 12. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting for some background information.

Comment: So,if I have a good understanding, I have to add up 12 columns _per row_ ?
If I don't use _.row_, stacking will be done according the number of columns ? A set of 24 columns width will be stacked to 2 lines ?

Comment: With the initial `.col-xs-8` you defined a column that is 8 out of 12 columns wide. With the `.form-group` you nest a new grid inside this column. This nested grid also consists of 12 columns that are smaller than columns in the parent grid.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is clear. I put it in the post description to help people.